# Fourier Tranform of $\frac {1}{(1+k \sin(t))^{3}}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm stuck with some Fourier transforms that I'm not being able to solve and Mathematica is not helping:
$\frac{1}{(1+k \sin(t))^{3}}$ (and the same one for sinh), where $k$ is a constant. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: check the existence conditions... The Fourier Transform of  this function doesn't exist.

Comment: This is a periodic function -- perhaps you're looking for its Fourier *series*?

Comment: 1) Different expressions in text and in question. 2) Fourier transform in the sense of distributions?

Comment: If k is between -1 and 1, you can find a convergent Fourier series by differentiating the geometric series twice and substituting -ksin(t) for x. The transform will be a bunch of Duracell Delta functions

Comment: Dirac delta functions, bad case of auto correct

Comment: You cannot expand the function as Fourier Series because the Dirichlet Fourier Series Conditions are not satisfied.